# Как правильно заносить значения в базу данных с php в MYSQL?

Tags: php

Ребята, всем привет.
Значит интересует следующий вопрос.
Есть таблица product. Есть стандартные поля, name, price, description. Так же есть таблица partner где заноситься информация о том кто занес информацию о товаре. Есть два поля. Partner и product_id.

Так вот, я написал веб интерфейс для клиентов, они добавляют товар, товар добавляется, но надо что бы и в таблицу partner была добавлена информация, а точнее id продукта. У таблицы product есть стандартное поле id. Изначально это поле неизвестно, после добавление он известно. Я использую функцию mysql_insert_id() и получаю последнее добавленное id и вставляют в таблицу partner. На сколько правильно я делаю? или совсем не в ту сторону копаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно наоборот всё делать добавлять id партнера в товар, чтобы по этому полю вывести товар загруженный этим или другим партнером.

Comment: я просто не хочу вносить много полей в одну таблицу, а то уже и так 15 полей получилось((((

Comment: @Eugene Smiths, простите, а какая разница?

Comment: в таблицу нужно вносить ровно столько данных, сколько нужно, не нужно пугаться количества.. главное - индексировать поля, по которым идет поиск

Comment: понятно! спасибо! всем!

Comment: @andreyqin по факту это связь "многие к одному", и реализация ее на стороне "одного" приведет к тому, что вместо одной записи будет зоопарк. Пока в таблице две колонки, партнер представлен одной строчкой и требуется только для отображения информации о продукте - ничего страшного, но лучше сделать все начисто сразу.